# MATLAB: How to determine connectivity among elements?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I am trying to determine how some elements are connected between one another by undestanding if they have a common coordinate.
I wrote the following code, but it is incorrect.

```
   clc
   clear
   lines = {[0 0 0; 0 0 3], [0 0 3; 1 2 2], [0 0 0; 1 2 2], [5 3 3; 0 0 0], [1 2 2; 5 2 3]}
   connectivity = []
   i = 1
   for i = 1:length(lines)-1
   [Result,LocResult] = ismember(lines{i},lines{i+1},'rows')
   if nonzeros(Result) == 1
   A = [i,i+1]
   connectivity = [connectivity; A]
   i = i + 1
   end
   end
```

Comment: It searches in merely one direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to identify where a row in a cell of lines, is repeated in another row in another cell of lines. The code below does that. In your code, you are only looking if the current cell has the same row as the cell right after it, which is not what you want I think.

You may want to generalize this to take into account the scale, i.e. that a row in a cell of lines may not be the exact same, but may be the same vector scaled. If that is what you want, use normalization of each row of lines before applying this method.

```
num_rows = size(lines{1},1);
C = zeros(length(lines));
for i = 1:length(lines)
    for j = 1:num_rows   
        A = lines{i}(j,:); % pick each row in lines and try to check if there are other elements of lines which have the same row
        for k = 1:length(lines)
            for m = 1:num_rows
                B = lines{k}(m,:);
                result = ismember(lines{i}(j,:),lines{k}(m,:),'rows'); 
                if result == 1 % means a match, so row in coordinate (i,j) is the same as (k,m)
                    % Return matrix C which says if lines{i} is connected
                    % to lines{k}. Diagonal is 1 since you have
                    % self-matching
                    C(i,k) = 1;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The initial number is part of the row and column of the matrix, like if lines{1} is connected to lines{3}, you get a C(1,3) = 1. Did you mean this?